# mysql query taking too much time for processing. how to solve this issue

Tags: mysql, select, count

```
 SELECT car_detail.*,
       (SELECT Count(tdid)
        FROM   testdrive
        WHERE  testdrive.carid = car_detail.detail_id)            AS vipdrive,
       (SELECT Count(fid)
        FROM   finanace_app
        WHERE  finanace_app.classified_id = car_detail.detail_id) AS financeapp,
       (SELECT Count(trid)
        FROM   tracking
        WHERE  tracking.carid = car_detail.detail_id
               AND track_mode = 'C')                              AS craigimp,
       (SELECT Count(trid)
        FROM   tracking
        WHERE  tracking.carid = car_detail.detail_id
               AND track_mode = 'L')                              AS landing
FROM   car_detail
WHERE  year <= '2011'
       AND price != '0'
       AND photo_count != ''
ORDER  BY (SELECT Count(tdid)
           FROM   testdrive
           WHERE  testdrive.carid = car_detail.detail_id)
          + (SELECT Count(fid)
             FROM   finanace_app
             WHERE  finanace_app.classified_id = car_detail.detail_id)
          + (SELECT Count(trid)
             FROM   tracking
             WHERE  tracking.carid = car_detail.detail_id)
          + car_detailed + picture_view + map_view
          + video_view DESC
```

Comment: You need to give more details if you expect anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things that stand out that could be improved:

## 1)

Correlated subqueries in the select list. Subqueries in general, and correlated subqueries in particular are slow, because they are ran for each row of the main query. You can rewrite these to subqueries in the from clause and join them.

## 2)

Query expression in the order by. These are slow for the same reason as subqueries in the SELECT list. And in this case, you're actually re-calculating values you already have, so you're doing the work twice. You should refer to the columns in the select list instead.

## 3)

You're querying the tracking table twice, once for track_mode = 'L' and once for track_mode = 'C'. It would make more sense to query it once and calculate two counts depending on the value of track_mode

```
SELECT     car_detail.*
,          vipdrive.testdrives
,          financeapp.finance_count
,          craigimp.tracking_count
,          craigimp.landing_count
FROM       car_detail
LEFT JOIN  (
           SELECT   Count(tdid) testdrives
           ,        testdrive.carid
           FROM     testdrive
           GROUP BY testdrive.carid
           )        vipdrive
ON         car_detail.detail_id = vipdrive.carid
LEFT JOIN  (
           SELECT   Count(fid) finance_count
           ,        finanace_app.classified_id
           FROM     finanace_app
           GROUP BY finanace_app.classified_id
           )        financeapp
ON         car_detail.detail_id = financeapp.classified_id
LEFT JOIN  (
           SELECT   SUM(if(track_mode = 'C', 1, 0)) tracking_count
           ,        SUM(if(track_mode = 'L', 1, 0)) landing_count
           ,        tracking.carid
           FROM     tracking
           GROUP BY tracking.carid
           )        craigimp
ON         car_detail.detail_id = craigimp.carid  
WHERE      year <= 2011
AND        price != 0
AND        photo_count != ''
ORDER  BY  vipdrive.testdrives
         + finance_count
         + tracking_count
         + car_detailed + picture_view + map_view
         + video_view DESC
```

Minor improvements are not quoting numeric constants.

As a general rule for performance questions, please do the following in the future:

- post nicely formatted SQL. Use this http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm?ref=g_wangz for example
- post SHOW CREATE TABLE output for each table in your query
- post EXPLAIN  output for your query.
- write down how long it is taking now, and how fast you would like it to be. You can always optimize more, so you need a goal otherwise it is an exercise with no end.

Comment: yes. am recalculating the values twices. can you simplify this mysql query . thx for reply

Comment: Can you please post nicely formatted SQL next time? It's taking a ton of time to reformat.

Comment: Hi this is working faster. but i can't get the totalvalue desc order when i run this query. thx very much

Comment: why not? what is the problem? Don't let us guess.

Comment: 20 times faster than before. Thx for this one. But it not desc the order by total values

Comment: Thx very much. i solved the issues. if you like can i be your friend

Comment: Glad you solved it. Care to share what the problem was?

Comment: ORDER  BY   tracking_count+landing_count+car_detailed + picture_view + map_view
         + video_view  DESC ";  i changed liked this

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the select inside the `order by` separately, and then use the result in the original query. 
Also, you're using the same table `tracking` twice in the subquery - you should merge the subselects  into one and use `case` or `if`.
If you want more help than that you'll have to run `Explain` and show us the result.

Comment: please explain and give me some examples

Comment: I can't `explain` only you can ;)